# Mixture of host and path based routing rules in traefik docker labels

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm trying to create a frontend rule using docker labels that directs both a couple host based routes *and* some path based routes from a domain to one backend but I'm having trouble getting the right magic for what turn out to be kind of complex rules.

`frontend.rule="Host:HostA.domain,HostB.domain,HostC.domain,Host:svc.domain;PathPrefix=/api/users, Host:svc.domain;PathPrefix=/api/other"`

This seemed like the right combination of *or* and *And* logic but I seem to be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `,` is the OR operator (works only inside a matcher, ex: `Host:foo.com,bar.com`)
- `;` is the AND operator (works only between matchers, ex: `Host:foo.com;Path:/bar`)

`Host:api.service;PathPrefixStrip:/foo`

To have a OR between matchers you need to use segment labels:

```
   # ...
   labels:
     - "traefik.enable=true"
     - "traefik.port=80"
     - "traefik.foo.frontend.rule=Host:api.mydomain.com"
     - "traefik.bar.frontend.rule=Host:www.mydomain.com,m.mydomain.com;PathPrefixStrp:/_"
   # ...
```

Documentation links:

- https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/basics/#matchers
- https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/basics/#combining-multiple-rules
- https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers-with-multiple-ports-segment-labels